# Yellow lines under Text Widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The main app screen doesn't have this issue, all the texts show up as they should.

However, in the new screen, all the text widget have some weird yellow line / double-line underneath.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

[image: Yellow Lines]

Comment: Can you add your code ?

Comment: I suspect the reason is because you do not have a Scaffold on this page.

Comment: @aziza
I think you're right. This page doesn't have a scaffold. I suspected that might be the issue, but didn't follow through with checking it.

Any ideas as to why this happens when I have no scaffold? I did not realise it was required. Should I just use a Scaffold anyway, even though I'm only gonna use the_body_ parameter?

Comment: Each page needs a Scaffold, even if you are refactoring smaller widgets onto separate classes they should end up with a Scaffold parent somewhere. I am not sure if it is meant this way for the text to be underlined or it is an issue, regardless, you will end up needing to build any page within a Scaffold.

Comment: Or if you donot want `Scaffold`, you can just surround your `Text` with `Material` widget

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Since I'm new to Flutter I couldn't figure out why my texts get double underline *by default*

Answer (score 402, accepted):

The problem is having a `Scaffold` or not.
`Scaffold` is a helper for `Material` apps (`AppBar`, `Drawer`, that sort of stuff). But you're not forced to use `Material`.

What you're missing is an instance of `DefaultTextStyle` as a parent:

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(...),
  child: Text('Hello world'),
)
```

Various widgets add one to change the default text theme, such as Scaffold, Dialog, AppBar, ListTile, ...

It's `DefaultTextStyle` that allows your app-bar title to be bold by default for example.

Comment: Also keep in mind for a Hero, it is disconnected from the parent while 'in flight' so adding a `Material` (or any Theme) as the Hero's child (BOTH sides) fixes it in the transition. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30647

Comment: @Rémi If you said Theme instance is missing in the parent, Why having Theme on top instead of Material or Scaffold doesn't help solve the problem? I just try it.

Comment: Just an update, It's the DefaultTextStyle, not Theme that's missing.

Comment: I just added another way to fix this in the answer below.

Comment: Adding a Theme parent does not solve the problem. `DefaultTextStyle` is the missing parent, as per [documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/52e2ca38fcacedf59ef519f15d05d20623473dab/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L22)

Comment: Scaffold adding as parent fixes the issue, Thanks!!

Comment: This is not an accurate answer. I have a Theme parent and the issue still exists.

Comment: Wrapping main widget within 'Scaffold' worked for me.

Answer (score 193):

Add `Material` widget as root element.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: new Container(
```

Comment: surrounding the `text` or `widget` with `Material` widget helped me. Adding Material as root element didn't help in my case

Comment: works both with `type: MaterialType.transparency` or without any.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `type: MaterialType.transparency,`. Needed it because my child had rounded borders so I was seeing a white background.

Answer (score 120):

All you need to do is provide a `Material` widget, or a `Scaffold` which internally covers this widget. You can do that in the following ways:

- ##### Use **`Material`** (simple and better):

  ```dart
  Material(
    color: Colors.transparent, // <-- Add this, if needed
    child: Text('Hello'),
  )
  ```
- ##### Set **`Text.style`** property:

  ```dart
  Text(
    'Hello',
    style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none), // Set this
  )
  ```
- ##### Provide `Scaffold`:

  ```dart
  Scaffold(body: Text('Hello'))
  ```

---

***Fixing yellow text issues when using `Hero`** :*

As [aaronvargas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114639/yellow-lines-under-text-widgets-in-flutter/54536853#comment100452496_47123685) mentioned, you can wrap your `child` in `Material` when using `Hero` on both sides. For example:

```dart
Hero(
  tag: 'fooTag',
  child: Material( // <--- Provide Material
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: YourWidget(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 48):

Text style has a decoration argument that can be set to none

```
Text("My Text",
  style: TextStyle(
    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
  )
);
```

Also, as others have mentioned, if your Text widget is in the tree of a Scaffold or Material widget you won't need the decoration text style.

Answer (score 18):

Just adding another way I encounter to these answers.

Wrap the root Widget around a [DefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) widget. Altering each Text widget is not a necessity here.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
    style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none), 
    child : Your_RootWidget
)
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 17):

Also you can use decoration: TextDecoration.none to remove underline

Answer (score 8):

You should add Material and Scaffold widgets in main.dart file

```
 MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Text('Hello world'),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Before**

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "21:34",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Wakey - wakey",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

**After (Solution):**

Here Wrap the current top or parent widget with `Scaffold` widget

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "21:34",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Wakey - wakey",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Full code:**[Dartpad or Live code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=cb6b283e113f69c2e04470c3c6691501)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: sta()));

class sta extends StatefulWidget {
  const sta({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<sta> createState() => _staState();
}

var isShow = false;


class _staState extends State<sta> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "21:34",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              "Wakey - wakey",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add Material root widget.

```
      @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Material(
         child: new Container(),
        );
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

**problem**: your widget doesn't have default text style,

**solution**: wrap it in one!

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
    style: TextStyle(),
    child: yourWidget,
  );
```

remember if you dont set any color, default text color is white!

Answer (score 2):

There is an other solution for this , especially if you are using multiple pages wrapped under **main.dart** file You can do something like this:

```
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: Material(child: Wrapper()),
  ),
```

This will remove the yellow lines under text that is present in any pages referenced/used under wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

The yellow lines come from [_errorTextStyle](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/52e2ca38fcacedf59ef519f15d05d20623473dab/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart#L22). The documentation states that you should define a `DefaultTextStyle` parent (or use `Material`, which does this for you):

> MaterialApp uses this TextStyle as its DefaultTextStyle to encourage developers to be intentional about their DefaultTextStyle.
>
> In Material Design, most Text widgets are contained in Material widgets, which sets a specific DefaultTextStyle. If you're seeing text that uses this text style, consider putting your text in a Material widget (or another widget that sets a DefaultTextStyle).

Developing Flutter apps without material is not something most people do, but if that's your use case, you should use `DefaultTextStyle`.

Contrary to the accepted answer, `Theme` does not set a `DefaultTextStyle`, so it does not solve your problem. `Scaffold` does solve the problem, as it contains `Material`, which in turn defines `DefaultTextStyle`, but `Scaffold` is a bit more than you need for a `Dialog`, `Hero`, etc.

To permanently solve this for your whole app, you could set the `DefaultTextStyle` in your `MaterialApp` `builder`. This solves the issue for all the components of your app, not just the current screen you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this approach because you could do it once and it will override your whole app.

Add `DefaultTextStyle` under `builder` of our `MaterialApp` like so:

```
child: MaterialApp(      
  ...
  ...
  theme: yourThemeData,
  builder: (context, child) => DefaultTextStyle(
    style: yourThemeData.textTheme.bodyText1,
    child: child,
  ),
),
```

By doing so we don't need to specify a `style` or having `DefaultTextTheme` every time we want to use `showDialog` or `Overlay`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have your scaffold as the home for your MaterialApp. This worked for me.

```
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Text('Test')),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a DefaultTextStyle() widget to set the textstyle of your text.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: kTempTextStyle,
  child: Text('Hello world'),
)
```

you can give your own textstyle as you want.

```
const kTempTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 100.0,
  decoration: null,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The text has a hidden default text style
.The problem arises because you can't provide this to any parent widget like **Scaffold**.
Text widget takes the default style.
for your solution either you can change the **DefaultTextStyle** like this.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
    style: TextStyle(),
    child: yourTextWidget,
  );
```

or just wrap into Scaffold, Scaffold is a widget. that provides scaffolding
for pages in your app.
like this

```
 MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Text('Wakey Wakey!'),
  ),
);
```

for more info just walk through this Flutter Official video.

[Yellow underline text | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUX1uVCewvk)

Answer (score 0):

wrap your build widget with Material widget

`@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Material ( ... );`

it will fix the text yellow underline issue

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping your widget with Material widget like a below:

```
Material(color: Colors.white, child: YourWidget())
```