# what is the route cause of Yellow underline for the Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter. I am preparing Login page. In the same, I am using a Text widget. For that i am getting Yellow double underline.

I am trying to fix with Scaffold as route layout

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Text('Test')
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Here is my Screenshot]

Comment: Manage to fix by myself after some searches, [You can see my updated code here](https://gist.github.com/MuthuHere/dbc7d959cf217e32d78beb0e3561c754)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yellow lines under Text Widgets in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114639/yellow-lines-under-text-widgets-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the parent of your `Scaffold` , `MaterialApp` should be the parent of all of your widgets tree.

```
  return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Text('Test')),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Remove all other only use text   

 return new Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: new Text(
                     "your text",
                      maxLines: 3,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),;
          ),
        );
```