# Get rid of double underlines in my Flutter UI

Tags: flutter

I need to get rid of the `underlines` that are present in the Flutter UI I made. I tried giving textStyle to this text but still doesn't get rid of the lines. I have added an image of how the output looks like below.

Any form of help will be appreciated, Thanks.

[image: Output]

Comment: can you please, share the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your Entire code with `Material` Widget

Comment: thanks a lot for this help... can u explain why this was happening?

Comment: Check this out :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114639/yellow-lines-under-text-widgets-in-flutter

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your widget with `Scaffold()` and add your widgets to the `body`.