# Flutter CupertinoContextMenu loses text styling on long press

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertino-widgets

I'm trying to add a `CupertinoContextMenu` to my app. The nested widget has a `Text` widget. The problem is that the `Text` widget loses its styling as soon as the user long presses the `CupertinoContextMenu`. I can fix this by wrapping my code in a `CupertinoApp`, but I don't want to do that. So my questions is, how can use a `CupertinoContextMenu` containing `Text` without wrapping my code with a `CupertinoApp`?

I also tried wrapping my code in a `CupertinoTheme`, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm using Flutter 3.16.3 and iOS 17.0.

**example**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CupertinoContextMenu.builder(
        actions: [
          CupertinoContextMenuAction(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: const Text("Test"),
          ),
        ],
        builder: (context, animation) {
          return const Center(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
              child: Text('Hello world'),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**expected**

[image: expected result]

**actual**

[image: actual result]

Comment: An answer below suggested this as a duplicate: [Yellow lines under Text Widgets in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114639/yellow-lines-under-text-widgets-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping `Material` to the `DecoratedBox`

**Code given below:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CupertinoContextMenu.builder(
        actions: [
          CupertinoContextMenuAction(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: const Text("Test"),
          ),
        ],
        builder: (context, animation) {
          return const Center(
            child: Material(
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                child: Text('Hello world'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add

`TextDecoration.none`
to your `Text`'s `textStyle`:

```dart
 Text(
        'Hello world',
        style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
      ),
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: I agree it's not great that bountied questions cannot be closed. The best way to deal with the situation is to bookmark the question and close it when one can.

Comment: Per the above I have cast a duplicate vote on the question.